# How to sort 2D array of objects according to the object property

Tags: php, arrays

I've a 2D array like this

```
$myArray = [
    0=>$Object,
    1=>$Object,
    2=>$Object,
    3=>$Object,
//etc...
]
```

Each objects has properties and some of them have the same name for example. How can I sort my Array so that objects with the same name follow each other and only if there is no other objects with the same name property, I go to the next name ?

```
$myArray = [
//Objects with the first name
    0=>$Object,
    1=>$Object,
    2=>$Object,
//Objects with the second name
    3=>$Object,
    4=>$Object,
//Objects with the third name
    5=>$Object,
// etc.
]
```

The array is generated from database so it will never have the same size and the number of objects with a name can be one or more.

Comment: What are your attempts & trials so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as below:

```
usort($dataArray, function($a, $b) {return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);});
```

or this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}

usort($dataArray, "cmp");
```

This will sort your data objects with property `name` with their values.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vn4Xn)